# On the class of real-valued functions which extensible to entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the class of real-valued functions $f(x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$, which are extensible to entire functions $\bar{f}(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\bar{f}(x)=f(x)$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Is $\mathcal{D}$ dense in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$? Any references?

Comment: Dense with respect to which topology?

Comment: Let us take, for instance, the distance between two functions to be the distance in L² norm

Comment: If everything is in L2 then just multiply by a smooth real valued even cutoff in Fourier space. The (inverse) Fourier of a compactly supported function is entire by Paley Wiener. It’s real valued since it’s the convolution with the inverse Fourier of the bump which is real valued since the bump was even and real valued. By making the support larger you get closer in L2 or any H^s

Comment: $L^2$ norm is not defined on all of $C^\infty.$

Comment: @zhw ok. Let us fix a suitable topology